# Abstracting the making of requests with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Traditionally I use jQuery for all my JS code, but I'm tasked to launch a simple API with node.js.  Today is my first day with Node but I know enough about JS and closures to do OK.  One of the tasks of the API is to authenticate across a third party service and being a python guy, I wanted to abstract all my outbound request calls like so:

**EDIT**

```
var http = require('http');

var init = function(nconf) {
    var methods = {
    /*  
        Helper method to create the request header
    */
    headers: function(params) {
        var content = JSON.stringify(params);
        return {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': content.length
        }
    },
    /*
        Helper method to create the options object
        which is used in making any type of 
        outbound http request
    */
    options: function(host, path, method, params) {
         return {
            host: host,
            port: 80,
            path: path,
            method: method,
            headers: methods.headers(params)
        }
    },
    /*
        Helper method to abstract the making of
        outbound http requests
    */
    call: function(options, params, success, err) {
        var req = http.request(options, success);
        req.on('error', err);
        req.write(params);
        req.end();
    },
    /*
        Helper method to parse the response
        and return a json object
    */
    parse: function(res, result) {
        var responseString = '';
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            responseString += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            result = JSON.parse(responseString);
        });
    },
    /*
        API method to return the latest
        release and tag names
    */
    latest: function(req, res, next){
        // // var url = nconf.get('prod:authenticate');

        //authenticate the test user
        msg = methods.authenticate(nconf.get('test:user'), nconf.get("test:password"));
        res.send(msg);

        next();

    },
    /*
        Method used by this API to authenticate users.
        It is used to de-couple this API from the Database
        Schema by calling out to the TTCPAS App and requesting it
        to handle the authentication

    */
    authenticate: function(username, password){
        // create post parameters with API key
        var params = {"username": username, "password": password, "api_key": nconf.get('api_key')};
        //construct options object with params and header
        var options = methods.options(nconf.get('ttcpas:host'), nconf.get('ttcpas:auth_url'), 'POST', params);
        var result;
        var success = function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');
            methods.parse(res, result);
        };
        methods.call(options, params, success, function(err){});
        while (typeof(result.statusCode) == 'undefined') {
            //wait 1 second;
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("waiting on request at " + nconf.get('ttcpas:host') + nconf.get('ttcpas:auth_url'));
            }, 1000);
        }
        //then down here
        if (result.statusCode == 200) {return result};//success
        if (result.statusCode == 403) {return "forbidden"};//forbidden


    }
}
return methods;
};
module.exports.init = init;
```

@jfriend00 As I said I don't know how node.js is supposed to be styled.  I wanted to just abstract as much as possible to make the code clean and reusable

Now when I do http://localhost:9000/latest/

I get:

```
{"code":"InternalError","message":"first argument must be a string or Buffer"}
```

Comment: If you think your code is working and you want thoughts on how to make it better, then this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  If your code is not working, then please describe what is not working so we can understand what you want help with fixing.

Comment: @jfriend00 fair point.  I still haven't started testing the code.  So I'll move it codereview

Comment: If the code is not tested, how do you know it works? Code Review is for working code only.

Comment: @rolfl I just tested it and got the error message: {"code":"InternalError","message":"first argument must be a string or Buffer"}

Comment: Still need to see how you intend to use this code when processing a request.   When I write an abstraction in a new environment, I don't start out writing the abstraction first.  I start out writing actual working code and as I see how that working code works, I discover things I can break out into common helper functions or common framework.  The finished code comes first and then I realize there are ways to take repeated code out of multiple handlers and make it common.  You're not explaining or demonstrating any of your motivation for that.

Comment: What is the motivation for abstracting beyond clean reusable code?  Isn't the word abstract code self describing?  I've written enough JS to know the areas where there are common reused code, like creating headers, or creating request parameters, or making request calls

Comment: OK, I'll leave this to others to comment on.  You do have to remove that `while` loop as it is an infinite loop and eventual server crash waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh, this part will simply not work:

```
while (typeof(result.statusCode) == 'undefined') {
    //wait 1 second;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("waiting on request at " + nconf.get('ttcpas:host') + nconf.get('ttcpas:auth_url'));
    }, 1000);
}
```

If `result.statusCode` is ever `undefined`, this will spin forever piling up `setTimeout()` calls in the event queue until eventually something fills up or you run out of memory.

Because node.js is primarily single threaded, you can't loop waiting for something to change.  Because you never finish this while loop, no other node.js code gets to run so `result.statusCode` can never change.  Thus, you have an infinite loop here.

All of your nodejs code needs to be event driven, not spin/wait loops.  FYI, this is similar to browser-based Javascript.

Comment: so how can I fix that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't follow the design or intent of the rest of your code and I don't understand why you're trying to make things so different from a typical nodejs app.  And, you've left out a lot of code (we can't even see the object these methods are wrapped in or how those objects are used.  There isn't enough info for me to understand what you're trying to accomplish or how this code is used.